# can i get the web in my local disk in php?

Tags: php

There is a free ftp space xxx.yyy.zzz , i upload the code (named  getweb.php) into it with filezilla.

```
<?php
$word=file_get_contents('http://www.webkaka.com/'); 
$filename='c:\\file.txt'; 
$fh=fopen($filename,"w");
echo  fwrite($fh,$word);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

when i inpu  xxx.yyy.zzz\getweb.php, i found that there is a file named `c:\file.txt` in my ftp space,i had to download it with filezilla.

I can do that with python ,how can  capture the web pages  directly into my local disk in php code ?
 ,

Comment: You just can't (or it's useless). You're suppesed to upload every file.

Comment: You can simply write a file directly from a web server to your local disk with Python? I highly doubt it.

Comment: just run the file on your local machine!?

Comment: the file is on the xxx.yyy.zzz(server side)  ,when it get the web ,let it be transferred into my local computer automatically.

Comment: can you explain your question some more clearly?

Comment: Need to know a few things: 1) are you wanting a script to do the downloading for you? Such as, a script connecting to a server and downloads a file. 2) will this file be downloaded to a local disk on a webserver, or to the local disk on a desktop, laptop, tab, whatever. 3) are you wanting the script to download the files using FTP? All of these can be done in any combination, you just need to be more clear to get your answer

Comment: @it_is_a_literature - take a loom at my answer and let me know a little more about your specific case if needed and I'll adjust it however needed.

Answer (score 1):

You must install PHP on your local computer if you want PHP code to be able to create files locally. You could try a ready-to-run XAMP package if you don't want to install native applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php 5, you can use file_put_contents:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $word);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to download a file using PHP's built-in FTP streams

```
// the file your trying to get
$file ="ftp://ftp_user:ftp_pass@domain.com/file.txt";

// get the file
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
```

Code to download a file using PHP's built-in HTTP streams

```
// the file your trying to get
$file ="http://domain.com/file.txt";

// get the file
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
```

Code to UPLOAD (put) file on remote FTP

```
// get the file from LOCAL HARD DRIVE
$contents = file_get_contents('C:/local/path/to/file.txt');

// the file your trying to UPLOAD
$file ="ftp://ftp_user:ftp_pass@domain.com/file.ext";

// write USING FTP
$opts = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents($file, $contents, NULL, $context);
```

OR COMBINE A FEW OF ABOVE: Download using FTP, upload using FTP

```
// the file your trying to get
$file ="ftp://ftp_user:ftp_pass@domain-ONE.com/file.txt";

// get the file USING FTP
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// the file your trying to UPLOAD
$file ="ftp://ftp_user:ftp_pass@domain-TWO.com/file.ext";

// write USING FTP
$opts = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents($file, $contents, NULL, $context);
```

Download using HTTP, upload using FTP

```
// the file your trying to get
$file ="http://domain-ONE.com/file.txt";

// get the file USING HTTP
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// the file your trying to UPLOAD
$file ="ftp://ftp_user:ftp_pass@domain-TWO.com/file.ext";

// write USING FTP
$opts = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents($file, $contents, NULL, $context);
```

This code can be ran remotely on a webserver, locally on a webserver, locally using php-cli, or remotely using php-cli over SSH.

Let me know your specific demands and i'll adjust my answer